# MLE based on bivariate data

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, order-statistics, exponential-distribution

Let $ x \sim Exp({\lambda}_{1}) , Y \sim Exp({\lambda}_{2})$ and are independent .
We observe Z and W with
Z = min(X, Y) and $W = \begin{cases} 1 &, if Z=X \\ 0 &, if Z = Y. \end{cases} $
Now assume that $( Z_i, W_i)$, i = 1, . . . , n, are n iid observations. Find the MLEs of $ {\lambda}_{1} $ and $ {\lambda}_{2} $.

I find the jt distribution of (Z,W) using cdf and conditional probability it's come up as $ e^{-\frac{z}{{\lambda}_1}} \frac{{\lambda}_1. {\lambda}_2}{{\lambda}_1+{\lambda}_2} $ when W=1 and replace ${\lambda}_1 by {\lambda}_2$ in exp then we will get for the case W=0 .
But then couldn't proceed .

Comment: you should include what you have tried and add the self-study tag

Comment: Yeah sorry . Now it's okay I think.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the standard parameterisation of the $\mathcal E(\lambda)$ distribution is *rather the inverse* of a scale, i.e., associated with the density and cdf
$$f(x)=\lambda\,e^{-x\lambda}\quad F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$$

With *this* representation, $Z=\min(X,Y)$ is distributed as $\mathcal E(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ and is independent of $W$, which is Bernoulli $\mathcal B(\lambda_1/\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$. The joint density is thus
$$f(z,w;\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\exp\{-z(\lambda_1+\lambda_2\}\lambda_1^w\lambda_2^{1-w}$$
The likelihood follows as $$\prod_{i=1}^n f(z_i,w_i;\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$$